unable to access samba share as one user, but I can as another user
I've got a Samba server configured on my server. I have my main account (nacho) and another account (`brother).
I have set Samba password for both using smbpasswd.
I can access shares using my nacho account but not my brother account.
I'm not sure what is wrong?
nacho@desk:~$ sudo testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
logging = file
map to guest = Bad User
max log size = 1000
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
registry shares = Yes
server role = standalone server
unix password sync = Yes
usershare allow guests = Yes
idmap config * : backend = tdb


[scans]
inherit acls = Yes
path = /home/nacho/brother scans
read only = No
valid users = brother nacho


[data]
inherit acls = Yes
path = /data
read only = No
valid users = nacho

nacho@desk:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -i brother
brother:x:1001:1001:brother,,,:/home/brother:/usr/sbin/nologin


Have you set a password for brother using sudo passwd brother? What are the permissions of /home/nacho/brother scans? If neither of these things turn out to be the problem, then I'd try and set obey pam restrictions to No + restart Samba just to see if it has something to do with that.

/home/$USER, /home/nacho in this case, has permissions of 750 in ubuntu now so only nacho can access anything beyond it.
A couple of options:
Set permissions on your home folder so that others can at least traverse it to get to the shared directory:
chmod 751 /home/nacho

Create the shared folder outside of your home folder ... say under /media/brother...
Change your share definition so that the "brother" user appears to be "nacho" after the correct credentials for brother are passed:
[scans]
inherit acls = Yes
path = /home/nacho/brother scans
read only = No
valid users = brother nacho
force user = nacho


Oh my gosh. I completely missed that. This was driving me bonkers but as soon as you said permissions -- that's when I realized. Thank you!
